# iOS 8.0.2 and iPhone plus when I set UIButton backgroundImage in XIB,UIButton become bigger though this button have autolayout with height and weight

Tags: uibutton, autolayout, background-image

iOS 8.0.2 and iPhone plus when I set UIButton backgroundImage in XIB,UIButton become bigger though this button have layout with height and weight after running

UIButton in xcode:

[image]

and layout :

[image]

but running in iPhone plus iOS8.0.2:

[image]

but in other iPhone like 5s,6  this button is ok!!!

the backgroundimage like this :

[image]

Comment: it is happening on device or just simulator?

Comment: is it happening specifically on iOS 8.0.2?

Comment: it is happening on device

Answer (score 0):

i have setup (https://github.com/usamaiqbal83/TestingProject) a repo for your case, it is not happening for me you can compare your setup with mine . i checked it on simulator

or if i am not able to understand your scenario clearly, kindly setup a repo i will gladly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

when I set the Image like this:

[image]

it is working .

I do not what has happen, but just it is.

any body know why it is?

Comment: like what? using asset catelog?